# How to drag and rotate a image in android webview smoothly

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, image-rotation

I have two images in the canvas. I have to rotate the circles on it's center only by dragging/rotating the finger on respective sides of the canvas. I have tried to move the circles using the touchmove event. But it does not matches the speed of the finger rotation as I have to pass the angle (set to a specific values). How can I move the circles smoothly, by matching the speed of the finger?